# Getting null when retrieving int from another class

Tags: java

Basically I made this programm where the computer generates a random card. I made a class called 'rndnumber', this class generates the random number. I then made another class called 'rndsuits', and this generates the random suit.
Problem is when I go to my main class, and execute the code, im getting null instead of numbers and suits. Anyone know why? My output is basically:
Here is your random card: null of null.

```
public class maincard { 

public static void main(String[] args){

    System.out.println("Here is your random card");

    rndnumber h = new rndnumber();
    rndsuit a = new rndsuit();


    System.out.println(h.getString() + " of " + a.getStringz());

}

}


public class rndnumber {

private int rndnumber = (int) (Math.random()*13+1);
private String number;

public String getString(){
    return number;
}


public void rnd(){
    switch (rndnumber){
    case 1:
        number = "Ace";
        break;
    case 2:
        number = "2";
        break;
    case 3:
        number = "3";
        break;
    case 4:
        number = "4";
        break;
    case 5:
        number = "5";
        break;
    case 6:
        number = "6";
        break;
    case 7:
        number = "7";
        break;
    case 8:
        number = "8";
        break;
    case 9:
        number = "9";
        break;
    case 10:
        number = "10";
        break;
    case 11:
        number = "Jacks";
        break;
    case 12:
        number = "Queens";
        break;
    case 13:
        number = "Kings";
        break;
    }

}   
}


public class rndsuit {

private int y = (int) (Math.random()*3+1);
private String rndsuit;

public String getStringz(){
return rndsuit;
}



public void suit(){
    switch(y){
    case 1:
        rndsuit = "Spades";
        break;
    case 2:
        rndsuit = "Cloves";
        break;
    case 3:
        rndsuit = "Hearts";
        break;
    case 4:
        rndsuit = "Diamonds";
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You really should use enums for such kids of data.

Answer (score 6):

You need to call the methods before getting the values.

```
h.rnd();
a.suit();
System.out.println(h.getString() + " of " + a.getStringz());
```

This will fix the null issue.

But there is another one issue waiting in the lounge for you. The above fix will return the same value always, unless you create a new object again and again and access value using that.

You need to move the random generator part in the methods like this for the `rnd()` and `suit()` to return new random values always.

```
public void suit() {
    y = (int) (Math.random() * 3 + 1);
    ...
}

public void rnd() {
    rndnumber = (int) (Math.random() * 13 + 1);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set them before getting.

You are setting values in `rnd()`, `suit()`  methods, but you are never calling them.

```
 rndnumber h = new rndnumber();
 h.rnd();

 rndsuit a = new rndsuit();
  a.suit();
 System.out.println(h.getString() + " of " + a.getStringz());
```

Until unless you call those methods, you end up with getting default value, that is `null`.

As a side note: Please please follow the [java naming conventions.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html),Class names starts with capital letter.

Comment: thanks for the help, got it fixed. But I have one more question, doesn't every method in the project execute when you compile it? Or does it only execute when you only call it from the main class?

Comment: Methods only get executed when called explicitly, constructors get called when a class is instantiated.

Comment: Only the `main()` will automatically execute. Constructors will be called when you instantiate and other methods(static or non-static) will be executed only when invoked explicitly by you.

Comment: No No. You have to call them manually when you need them to do specific task

Answer (score 0):

You never initialize the `String` fields `rndsuit` and `rndnumber` so they are `null`.

Consider adding a constructor to both classes that will initialize the `int` as well as the `String` fields.

For example

```
public class RandomSuit  {
    // theses should never change so make them final
    private final int y;
    private final String rndsuit;

    public RandomSuit() {
       this.y = (int) (Math.random()*3+1);
       this.rndsuit = rnd(y);
    }
    // find the String representation of the random number 
    private static String rnd(rndnumber){
      switch (rndnumber){
      case 1:
          return "Spades";
      case 2:
          return "Cloves";
       ...
       }
    }
    //override Object's toString instead of using getString
    @Override
    public String toString(){
       return rndsuit;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are instantiating new objects but the constructor is not assigning random numbers to the variables inside the classes.

```
rndnumber h = new rndnumber();
```

is creating a new object. But at no point is the String number set to anything inside that class.

```
private String number;
```

Later you return that string, which is still null.

```
public String getString(){
    return number;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by adding constructors to the `rndnumber` and `rndsuit` classes as folows.

Add following to the `rndnumber` class :

```
public rndnumber() {
    rnd();
}
```

Add this to the rndsuit class :

```
public rndsuit() {
    suit();
}
```